# Usage of metaphor indicating repetitious occurence of bad things

Tags: metaphors

I intend to use the metaphor **tempest-toosed upon life's billows** in the sentence below. Would the usage of the preceding metaphor sound awkward to the english native speaker? Or is there any other phrase to replace it?

> The accident caused the death of the deceased. It is no small wander a tragic incident to the deceased's family. And seemingly tempest-tossed upon life's billows, there was no witness to support the family's claim for negligence in court.

Comment: As a quotation from an old hymn (as discussed in [your earlier post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/271886/meaning-of-the-phrase-tossed-upon-lifes-billow) ), it isn't really a suitable metaphor for describing a modern situation. If you do use it, you should put it in inverted commas to show that it is a literary quotation. Also, your sentence doesn't say _who_ has been 'tempest-tossed'.

Comment: Thank you very much for assisting me.